# Sharepoint 2010 autogenerated workflow column

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

is it possible to change order of workflow autogenerated column (from last position to 2nd)? I need to do this programatically, not in Library > Modify view.

**EDIT:**
Whole workflow I made in Visual Studio and it is with custom association, initiation an task form.

**EDIT2:**
I figured it out, just reorder view in onWorkflowActivated method:

```
private void onWorkflowActivated_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        string colName = workflowProperties.TemplateName;
        SPView defaultView = workflowProperties.List.DefaultView;
        if (defaultView.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains(colName))
        {       
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection collStrings = defaultView.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
            List<string> fields = new List<string>();
            foreach (string field in collStrings)
            {
                fields.Add(field);
            }

            if (fields.IndexOf(colName) != 2)
            {
                defaultView.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo(colName, 2);
                defaultView.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? Do you want to modify/create a view programatically or do you need a different column order elsewhere?

Comment: I want to reorder columns after workflow association. I need autogenerated column on 2nd place, because it is hard to read list with 30+ columns if list item is Approved/Rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the logic of how your workflow is associated to the list by creating a custom workflow association page and code behind. You should look into this documentation as a starting point:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481192.aspx

Comment: thanks for reply,
I already have custom association and initiation form for my workflow.